# Scrapy loop to find each element and export to Json

Tags: python, scrapy

Code below locates all the elements I am looking for but I am struggling to put this is a loop where data gets put into a dataframe and exported out to a Json file. All the commands work from the command line to bring in the data I need. How can I get his to export a json?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class WeatherdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'weatherdata'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.nflweather.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://https://www.nflweather.com//']

    def parse(self, response):
        #pass
        trans_table = {ord(c): None for c in u'\n\t\t'}
        Datetime = '    '.join(s.strip().translate(trans_table) for s in response.xpath('//div[@class="fw-bold text-wrap"]/text()').extract())
        awayTeam = response.xpath('//span[@class="fw-bold"]/text()').extract()
        homeTeam = response.xpath('//span[@class="fw-bold ms-1"]/text()').extract()
        TempProb    = response.xpath('//div[@class="mx-2"]/span/text()').extract()
        windspeed = response.xpath('//div[@class="text-break col-md-4 mb-1 px-1 flex-centered"]/span/text()').extract()
```

Comment: why do you need a dataframe, just create a data structure that the JSON module can use to dump to a JSON text format, no need to use Pandas

Comment: Sorry that was my ignorance still new to python. I was under the impression that to export the data to json I need it to be in a dataframe first

Comment: @LeoTorres [see this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-exports). Also search here on SO, there are multiple examples of how to use it.

Comment: A couple of quick comments: (1) your `allowed_domains` should just contain a DNS name (should not be an URL but just `www.nflweather.com`) and (2) your `start_urls` has `http://https://`, which should be just `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re
import scrapy


class WeatherdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'weatherdata'
    allowed_domains = ['www.nflweather.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.nflweather.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        trans_table = {ord(c): None for c in u'\n\t\t'}

        date = response.xpath('//div[@class="fw-bold text-wrap"]/text()').extract()
        date = [d.strip().translate(trans_table) for d in date]

        wind = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "text-break")]/span[not(ancestor::span)][2]/text()[1]').extract()
        wind = [re.sub(" \xa0", "", w) for w in wind]

        away = response.xpath('//span[@class="fw-bold"]/text()').extract()
        home = response.xpath('//span[@class="fw-bold ms-1"]/text()').extract()
        temp  = response.xpath('//div[@class="mx-2"][1]/span/text()').extract()
    
        for date, home, away, temp, wind in zip(date, home, away, temp, wind):
            yield {
                "date": date,
                "home": home,
                "away": away,
                "temp": temp,
                "wind": wind,
            }
```

I understand why you were wanting to use a Data Frame, but with this approach it's not necessary. You scrape all of the items off the page into separate lists, then iterate over them in parallel, yielding one item at a time.

Run it like this:

```bash
scrapy crawl weatherdata -O weather.json
```

That will dump the data to a JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "date": "01/20/24 04:30 PM EST",
    "home": "Ravens",
    "away": "Texans",
    "temp": "27 °F",
    "wind": "16 mph"
  },
  {
    "date": "01/20/24 08:15 PM EST",
    "home": "49ers",
    "away": "Packers",
    "temp": "58 °F",
    "wind": "5 mph"
  },
  {
    "date": "01/21/24 03:00 PM EST",
    "home": "Lions",
    "away": "Buccaneers",
    "temp": "23 °F",
    "wind": "10 mph"
  },
  {
    "date": "01/21/24 06:30 PM EST",
    "home": "Bills",
    "away": "Chiefs",
    "temp": "18 °F",
    "wind": "10 mph"
  }
]
```

I piped the JSON through `jq` to make it easier to read.

```bash
jq . weather.json
```